# Mysql - Replicate only a few tables from a database

Tags: mysql, database-replication, mysqlbinlog

Using mysql replication with mysqlbinlogs between master and slave databases, is it possible to only replicate a few key tables instead of an entire database?

1. I would ideally like to not even generate the mysqlbinlogs for the unneeded tables
2. If that was not possible, could I then use the slave with the limited tables and set up another master-slave that would result in the limited mysqlbinlogs?

Comment: An article on the subject: https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/11/07/filtered-mysql-replication/

Answer (score 1):

Binlog will be generated for all tables. Use the [blackhole](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blackhole-storage-engine.html) storage engine on another mysql instance to filter the binlog. Here is a guide: http://jroller.com/dschneller/entry/mysql_replication_using_blackhole_engine

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But I'm not quite clear on how the blackhole storage engine would help me filter the binlog, could you elaborate please?

Comment: You set up a slave server that does a binary log. Use `replicate-ignore-db` and similar settings to filter which tables to replicate. Use `BLACKHOLE` storage for all tables. This server will write a new smaller binlog with those tables which you can use as master for other slaves.